# QGIS - WGS84 to BC Albers reprojection no curved lines, any idea why? How to snap a line to a point?

Tags: qgis, point, coordinate-system, snapping, cad

I am trying to learn a bit about QGIS.  So I thought I would drop in some layers of my Province and then recreate some points representing the BC Albers Central Meridian, and the two standard parallels.

Why when I reproject my straight lines from WGS84 to BC Albers do they not curve like they should?  I drew them in WGS84 as the image illustrates.

I hope I have outlined my problem clearly, if not please ask for clarification.

I would appreciate any input on this, thanks!

I could not post my picture illustrating this problem but hopefully it is accessible on my dropshots account: http://www.dropshots.com/stwomey%23date/2012-05-19/11:13:44

Well it looks like the link doesn't go directly to the picture...  darn it!

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. If I understand your problem correctly, you have two independent questions. Please post them in separate threads so they can be answered on their own. Since the first question has been addressed already, I'll remove the second one. Please re-post it in a new thread.

Comment: Did you create a second account on purpose? I can merge the accounts so you can keep ownership of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick guess for question #1: QGIS only projects vertices and your straight lines have only an start- and endpoint?

Comment: So the shapefiles I had were reprojected properly. The shapefiles must be made up of lots of vertices? I never realized only the vertices get projected! Now I see the use for the creating points at a specified distance tool. Thanks.